# Is the Celestron astromaster 130 EQ Model able to see nebulas and galaxies?

Tags: telescope

[image]

Is the Celestron astromaster 130 EQ Model able to see nebulas and galaxies?
If this telescope is not able to see nebulae, please suggest me the best one telescopes for nebulas.

Comment: Hello Het Mistry,  Welcome to the site. Can I ask you to [edit] some improvements to your question:  Tell us what research you have done, for example have you searched this site and others?  Please remove the request to "answer quickly"  We aren't being paid so we do this in our own time. Please remove the request for "best one". This is a subjective matter. What is "best" for you might not be best for me. We don't do product recommendations. Please take a look at the [tour] so see how we work here.

Comment: And what are the circumstances at the places where you are observing? Anything special regarding dust, light, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't whether you can see deep-sky objects but how many.
Given a reasonably dark observing site, the Orion nebula and the Andromeda galaxy are visible in 7x50 binoculars.
A 130mm objective should be enough to see most of the nebulae and galaxies in the [Messier catalogue](http://www.messier.seds.org/xtra/similar/dataRASC.html).
Once you get the hang of it, you may be able to see a few [NGC objects](http://www.messier.seds.org/xtra/similar/rasc-ngc.html) too, but a bigger scope will show more of them.

Comment: I've linked to http://www.deepskywatch.com/Articles/what-can-i-see-through-telescope.html for other similar questions.  This telescope would be at the small end of the "medium" catagory.

Comment: I'd like to add that the number of galaxies and nebulae you can see can easily be influenced as much by the darkness of your skies as by the size of the telescope.  From many urban locations, it's hard to see more than one or two nebulae.